# toggle button controlled popup

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: this is how the popup looks at the beginning and when i press "profiles" for the first time , the popup reopens rather than going down.] 
[image: but the second time press the profile button , the popup works as desired,the issue is there only for the first time]

I have a popup that opens when we click on the toggle button. I have written a converter such that popup closes whenever we click on toggle button again or when we click anywhere other than the popup.
the XAML code is this

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="m_XYProfileBtn"  Content="Profiles" Height="24" Style="{DynamicResource StatusFlatToggle}"
                               Visibility="{Binding IsToggleStatusVisibility}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPopUpOpen}"  />
<Popup Margin="5" Name="ProfilePopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Width="400" Height="500" AllowsTransparency="True"
                           IsOpen="{Binding IsPopUpOpen}"
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide"
                           Placement="Top"
                           VerticalOffset="-4"
                           HorizontalOffset="2"
                           >
<Popup.StaysOpen>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBinding_StayOpen}">
        <Binding ElementName="m_XYProfileBtn"  Path="IsMouseOver"/>
        <Binding ElementName="Pin" Path="IsChecked" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Popup.StaysOpen>
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.95*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Name="Pin" Content="Pin" Style ="{StaticResource PinBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Grid Name="xProfileGrid" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

and the C# converter code is this

```
public class MultiBinding_StayOpen : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        bool toggleIsMouseOver;
        bool pinIsChecked;

        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        toggleIsMouseOver = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        pinIsChecked = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);

        if (pinIsChecked == true)
            return true;
        else if (toggleIsMouseOver == true)
            return true;
        else if (toggleIsMouseOver == false)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works fine but the first time you click on the toggle button, popup opens up again in place of closing. After that it works perfectly. Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: can u show small screenshot that what is happening?

Comment: i  have uploaded a screenshot. i hope it will you understand the issue

Comment: `ToggleButton` binds its IsChecked to IsPopupOpen - the multibinder only looks at the `ToggleButton`.`IsMouseOver` and `IPin.IsChecked` - why does it not multibind against `ToggleButton.IsChecked || Pin.IsChecked || ToggleButton.IsMouseOver`  ?   Converter could be streamlined: `if (pinIsChecked || toggleIsMouseOver) { return true; } else { ... }` but it looks fine. Btw. If you put a Sleep your thread is sleeping - you could also use a timer with an Dispatcher.Invoke( () =>  ... ) to close the popup to leave your UI responsive. All those small sleeps add up to something unpleasant.